# How would i make this repeat?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an alarm notification and I want it to repeat when this 2 radio buttons are active.

[image]

I have this code :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Radio_Msg.IsChecked) {
        CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastWarning("Alarme");
    }


    if (Radio_Notif.IsChecked) {
        CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Miguel", "Módulo 19 – Tecnologias de Acesso a Base de Dados");
    }

    if (Radio_Msg.IsChecked && RadioRepetir == true) {
        CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage("Tesddddte");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage("Teste");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't repeat it, it only prints one notification out.

Comment: Just FYI. This is bad UX. Radio button groups should be single selection only. You are probably looking for checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Radio_Msg.IsChecked && RadioRepetir == true)
        {

            var minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.2);

            Device.StartTimer(minutes, () => {

                CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastWarning("Alarme");
               
                return true;
            });
```